# GPS not turned on after geolocation permissions in webview?

Tags: javascript, android, kotlin, webview, geolocation

Help! I'm completely stuck with my webview app. The website page in my webview app shows a Google maps with the current posistion of the user. But i can't figure out why my code is not working properly? My webview ask for Geolocation permission when the user enter the app, but after giving the Geolocation permissions, the GPS is not turn on, and the G-maps shows nothing? In app-info >> permissions >> location is allowed. In chrome browser this all works perfect, but in my webview app nothing happens,

```
   class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
        this, arrayOf(
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION
        ), 0
    )


    val UrlWindow: WebView = findViewById(R.id.UrlWindow)
    UrlWindow.webViewClient = object : WebViewClient (){
        override fun shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view: WebView?, url: String?): Boolean {
            if (url != null) {
                view?.loadUrl(url)
            }
            return true
        }
    }

    UrlWindow.settings.javaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically = true
    UrlWindow.settings.databaseEnabled = true
    UrlWindow.setWebChromeClient(object : WebChromeClient() {
        override fun onGeolocationPermissionsShowPrompt(
            origin: String,
            callback: GeolocationPermissions.Callback
        ) {
            callback.invoke(origin, true, false)
        }
    })

    UrlWindow.settings.javaScriptEnabled = true
    UrlWindow.settings.setGeolocationEnabled(true)
    UrlWindow.loadUrl("https://mywebsite.com")

}

override fun onBackPressed() {
    if (UrlWindow.canGoBack()) {
        UrlWindow.goBack()
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed()
    }
}

}
```

and my manifest

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.myapp" >

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_GPS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_ASSISTED_GPS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Any help is welcome!!

Answer (score 1):

Do the initialization of the webview once you got the result of the permissions in `OnRequestPermissionResult` callback.

```
override fun onRequestPermissionsResult(
        requestCode: Int,
        permissions: Array<out String>,
        grantResults: IntArray
    ) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults)
       //Do the permission check here
       initializeWebView()

    }
```

Also the recommended steps are,

1. First check permission
2. If not given required permission, then request them.
3. Do the permission based task once you got the permission status in `OnRequestPermissionResult` callback.